# pytest ImportError

Tags: python, pytest

My folder layout is roughly like this

```
mesa/
    └── mesa
        └── __init__.py
        └── some module files
    └── tests
```

When I run `pytest --cov=mesa tests/` in the topmost mesa folder, I received the following error messages (only a snippet)

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
__________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_batchrunner.py __________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/kumom/Documents/Projects/mesa/tests/test_batchrunner.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_batchrunner.py:8: in <module>
    from mesa import Agent, Model
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'Agent'
```

Why would this happen even when `__init__.py` file exists?

Comment: Check your `PYTHONPATH` You can also try setting it to the root directory and run test cases, something like `export PYTHONPATH=`$PWD`` from your root directory.

Answer (score 0):

it probably tries to import from top-most mesa/ and not from mesa/mesa/